# How to retrieve email address after the recipient click on a button inside email

Tags: email

I am working on a web apps with Asp.Net (C#) and I have a problem like this:

I will sent out an email for more than one person and there is a link in the email. If user click on the link I want to retrieve the email address of the respondent (as query string or whatever).

Is it possible?

How should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you send a single mail to multiple recipients or one for each?

Comment: Yes, I send a single email to multiple recipients.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I cannot imagine there's a solution for that, because IMO that would be a major security issue...

Comment: Yes, I have totally no idea, I am wondering is there any API of email service (i.e. Gmail) can be used to retrieve that?

Comment: I would be very suprised if any email client allowed to run scripts from inside the email. Most don't even show images from remote sources.

Comment: If this really isn't possible, the obvious workaround would be to send the email to each recipient seperately and then apply Henrik's approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you generate the emails dynamically, you can add a token to the url that is unique to each email address you send to. Your landing page will use the tokens to register a hit to a database.

On another note, please remember to handle information like email addresses with great care (i.e. securely), for example when storing them in a database.